# Keep nav bar float on top of all other content

Tags: html, css

So, I didn't exactly know how to word the title because every google search relative to these keywords always leads me to people only wanting to make the nav bar scroll with the page using `position:fixed;`. That is NOT what I want to do, but I must say that I am a little embarrassed that I've started a business making websites as a web design enthusiast going into college. What I want to happen is that I want the child menus of the navigation bar [on my website](http://aparturecreations.com/about-aparture.php) to show on top of the other content. I have tried `position:fixed;` on the child menus, and while the parent anchors don't follow the screen, when hovering the cursor over a certain part of the screen, the child menus will still drop 35px off the top of the page, even when the nav bar isn't visible on the page. All I want is for the child menus to be on top of all other content. And yes, I have tried `position:relative; z-index:99;` on the menus with no luck of it staying on top of the z-axis. Anyone have any ideas? I'll have a snippet of the navigation bar CSS below

```
.menu{
    height:40px;
}
.menu li{
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    height:40px;
}
.menu li a{
    display:block;
    padding:15px;/*t r b l*/
    line-height:30px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#F9F9F9;
    -webkit-transition:color .15s linear;
    -moz-transition:color .15s linear;
    -o-transition:color .15s linear;
    -ms-transition:color .15s linear;
    transition:color .15s linear;
}
.menu li:hover > a{
    color: #C00;
    background:rgba(38, 38, 38, 1);
}
.menu ul{
    font-weight:300;
    position:absolute;/*relative positioning will turn this into a vertical nav bar, and absolute positioning will hide behind the white section below*/
    opacity:0;
    width:150px;
    border-bottom:4px solid #C00;
    box-shadow:0 .9em .9em rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    -webkit-transition:height .1s linear;
    -moz-transition:height .1s linear;
    -o-transition:height .1s linear;
    -ms-transition:height .1s linear;
    transition:height .1s linear;
}
.menu li:hover > ul{
    opacity:1;
    background:rgba(38, 38, 38, 1);
}
.menu ul li{
    height:0;
    -webkit-transition:height .1s linear;
    -moz-transition:height .1s linear;
    -o-transition:height .1s linear;
    -ms-transition:height .1s linear;
    transition:height .1s linear;
}
.menu li:hover > ul li{
    font-size:10px;
    width:190px;
    margin-left:-40px;
    background:rgba(38, 38, 38, 1);
    height:30px;
    border-bottom:rgba(46, 46, 46, 1) 1px solid;
    border-top:rgba(30, 30, 30, 1) 1px solid;
}
.menu ul li a{
    padding:0 0 0 10px;
    height:inherit;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

I do apologize about the mess of code and the amount of time it will take to analyze all that, but it's not as bad as it looks. I will gladly explain what is happening on the page if anyone has questions or concerns.

Comment: Can't you add some drawings/sketches to explain your idea?

Comment: I have included a page affected in the post. when you hover over a parent tag, the child tag hides behind the rest of the content. I just wanted it to be on top of the other content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the web provided in the question ( http://aparturecreations.com/about-aparture.php ) , the `<div>` with the class `"bannerContent"`, that is placed just before the `<body>` in the web provided in the question, have `overlfow:hidden`. Remove it and everything will work fine

```
.bannerContent {
  background: #D0D0D0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

Should be

```
.bannerContent {
   background: #D0D0D0;
   width: inherit;
   height: inherit;
   min-height: 200px;
}
```

**EDITED:**

The most easy solution if you want to keep the gradient in this situation is to fix the height in this `<div>` rather to make it inherit

```
.bannerContent {
   background: #D0D0D0;
   width: inherit;
   height: 300px;
   min-height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: I like this, but I have a weird silver gradient bar above the body content, would you happen to have a fix for this as well? and thank you. That was exactly what I was looking for